# What is the "circle-plus" symbol I see in Abstract Algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, soft-question

Sorry if this comes off as a random or soft question. I keep seeing this symbol in my abstract algebra course  where it is a plus sign inside of a circle. I am not sure what it means.

Can someone please help me? Sorry if this bothers anyone.

Thanks.

Comment: I think it is a direct sum.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_sum

Comment: What a pity you didn't give an example or the name of your textbook.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's most likely the [direct sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_sum) symbol.

The direct sum $A\oplus B$ of two abelian groups/rings/modules $A$ and $B$ is the cartesian product $A\times B$ as sets with the obvious relation $(a,b)\ast_{A\oplus B}(c,d)=(a\ast_A c,b\ast_B d)$ where $\ast$ is the addition in the respective object (multiplication is similarly defined if you're working in a ring/module).